# How can I make a material randomize a texture per object?

Tags: texturing, materials, random

Let's imagine I have a scene with a thousand identical cube meshes. I want to apply the same material to all cubes, but have each cube randomly display one of my 3 or 4 image textures. Say, some cubes will be checkered, others will be dotted and others will be striped for example.

Is there a simple way to achieve this in Blender 3.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be a more intelligent solution but you could use an *Input > Object Info* node and its *Random* output to mix your *Image Texture* nodes through a *Color > Mix Color* node, plug the *Object Info* into a *Color Ramp* in *Constant* mode so that it picks one or the other image randomly:

[image]